# Ask for Directory in VB from button click event in Access

Tags: vba, event-handling, directory

I am totally new to VB so please excuse my inexperience. I have a form in Access that has a button named "Command17". When the user clicks the button I need it to ask for the user to enter a directory. This is a project started by someone else and all I see in the VB window is this:

Can anyone  help?

[image]

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/916710-select-file-folder-using-filedialog-object

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: I'm actually just taking over this project. Someone gave it to me and said hey we need this by Friday. All it has is a form with two buttons however there is no code tied to either button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the directory file dialog object of the application and return the path string:

```
Dim intResult As Integer
Dim strPath As String
intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show '<-- show the folder picker
If intResult <> 0 Then '<-- if the user didn't cancel
MsgBox Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1), vbInformation, "Selected Folder" '<--here the selected folder's path that you can use for your scopes
End If
```